# Java socket not receiving exact message

Tags: java, c#, sockets, socket.io, serversocket

Im sending a message from an android device to the server app in c#... i have successfully sent message from mobile device and received or server but a message from server is not being received in its original form on mobile device...

**C# code for sending message**

```
         if (message == "Share_Screen")
          {
            string msg = "Go to java Socket in Android";

            byte[] bfr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("No of bytes to be send are "+bfr.Length);
            socket.Send(bfr);
          }
```

**Java Code for Sending and receiving single message**

```
        try
        {

            Socket socket = new Socket(ip,5353);
            byte[] receiverBuffer = new byte[28];
            byte[] buffer = "Share_Screen".getBytes();

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);

            //sending successfully this message to c# socket
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataInputStream.read(receiverBuffer);

            String msg = receiverBuffer.toString();

            dataOutputStream.close();
            dataInputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            return msg;
            //expected message is " Go to java Socket in Android "
            //received message is " |b@52a5395c "
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return "error";
        }
```

*message im receiving in android device is like "|b@52a5395c"*

Comment: ToString does not what you think it does.

Comment: thank u sir.... yes it doesn't work the way i thought!!!!!!
it has to be like 
String msg = new String(receiverbuffer);